# How to programmatically run JUnit DynamicTest, from a Java Application

Tags: java, junit5

I'd like to know if it's possible to run JUnit5 DynamicTests programmatically?

I have read the article:
https://www.baeldung.com/junit-tests-run-programmatically-from-java
that shows how to run traditional package/file based tests.

I'm able to easily enough create a hierarchy of dynamic tests using:

- org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicContainer
- org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicNode
- org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest

I have investigated the Launcher, Discovery mechanisms, Test Engines - but I don't see an obvious solution.

Ideally i want to avoid using the @TestFactory annotation in a traditional test file.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Copy the code from Jupiter Engine?
Why don't you want to use `@TestFactory`? What is "a traditional test file"?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I'd rather use JUnit a as dependency rather than copy and maintain code from it. Having thought about it I could still achieve my goal by using the @TestFactory and programatically launch the test as described in the article linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You need an engine in your main class path, I suggest to use one provided by junit (with Gradle):

```
implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.0'
implementation (
  [group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version:'5.4.0'],
  [group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version:'1.4.0']
)
```

Then, create a TestFactory:

```
public class MyTestFactory {

    @TestFactory
    Collection<DynamicTest> dynamicTestCollection() {
        return Arrays.asList(DynamicTest.dynamicTest(
                "pipeline toto",
                () -> Assertions.assertEquals(2, Math.addExact(1, 1)))
        );
    }

}
```

And create a launcher:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(
                    selectPackage(" org.qwant.datahub.djobi.tester.runners"),
                    selectClass("MyTestFactory")
                )
        .build();

        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();

        SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
        launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);


        launcher.execute(request);

        TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();

        summary.printTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute it.

```
List<DynamicTest> tests = streamBuilder.build().toList();
for (DynamicTest test : tests) {
    test.getExecutable().execute();
}
```